# Eloquent select where relation has at least one result

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

So I have `Order`, `OrderItem` and `Product`.

```
class Order extends Model
{

public function items()
{
    $this->hasMany(OrderItem::class);
}

}

class OrderItems extends Model
{

public function product()
{
    $this->hasOne(Product::class);
}

}
```

I need to select all the orders where has at least one order item which has a product with type physical.

```
Order::whereHas('items.product', function ($itemQuery) use ($productType) {
    $itemQuery->whereIn('type_type', $productType);
});
```

This returns orders with only physical products.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Order::whereHas('items', function ($itemQuery){
    $itemQuery->whereHas('product', function($product) use ($productType) {
        $product->whereIn('type_type', $productType);
    });
});
```